# Iterating over PE files

Tags: python, data-science, n-gram

Below is part of my code in which I am trying to iterate over PE files. I am still getting the same error which is:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//FlickLearningWizard.exe'

Tried using `os.path.join(filepath)` but it does not do anything since I am have already made the path. I got rid of '/' but it did not add much. Here is my code:

```
B = 65521
T = {}
for directories in datasetPath: # directories iterating over my datasetPath which contains list of my pe files
    samples = [f for f in os.listdir(datasetPath) if isfile(join(datasetPath, f))]
    for file in samples:
        filePath = directories+"/"+file
        fileByteSequence = readFile(filePath)
        fileNgrams = byteSequenceToNgrams(filePath,N)
        hashFileNgramsIntoDictionary(fileNgrams,T)
K1 = 1000
import heapq
K1_most_common_Ngrams_Using_Hash_Grams = heapq.nlargest(K1, T)
```

And here is my complete error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-eb8b9254ac6d> in <module>
      6     for file in samples:
      7         filePath = directories+"/"+file
----> 8         fileByteSequence = readFile(filePath)
      9         fileNgrams = byteSequenceToNgrams(filePath,N)
     10         hashFileNgramsIntoDictionary(fileNgrams,T)

<ipython-input-3-4bdd47640108> in readFile(filePath)
      1 def readFile(filePath):
----> 2     with open(filePath, "rb") as binary_file:
      3         data = binary_file.read()
      4     return data
      5 def byteSequenceToNgrams(byteSequence, n):
```

A sample of the files I am trying to iterate through in which is in the datasetpath:

```
 ['FlickLearningWizard.exe', 'autochk.exe', 'cmd.exe', 'BitLockerWizard.exe', 'iexplore.exe', 'AxInstUI.exe', 'fvenotify.exe', 'DismHost.exe', 'GameBarPresenceWriter.exe', 'consent.exe', 'fax_390392029_072514.exe', 'Win32.AgentTesla.exe', '{71257279-042b-371d-a1d3-fbf8d2fadffa}.exe', 'imecfmui.exe', 'HxCalendarAppImm.exe', 'CExecSvc.exe', 'bootim.exe', 'dumped.exe', 'FXSSVC.exe', 'drvinst.exe', 'DW20.exe', 'appidtel.exe', 'baaupdate.exe', 'AuthHost.exe', 'last.exe', 'BitLockerToGo.exe', 'EhStorAuthn.exe', 'IMTCLNWZ.EXE', 'drvcfg.exe', 'makecab.exe', 'licensingdiag.exe', 'ldp.exe', 'win33.exe', 'forfiles.exe', 'DWWIN.EXE', 'comp.exe', 'coredpussvr.exe', 'AddSuggestedFoldersToLibraryDialog.exe', 'InetMgr6.exe', '3_4.exe', 'CIDiag.exe', 'win32.exe', 'LanguageComponentsInstallerComHandler.exe', 'sample.exe', 'Win32.SofacyCarberp.exe', 'EASPolicyManagerBrokerHost.exe', '131.exe', 'AddInUtil.exe', 'fixmapi.exe', 'cmdl32.exe', 'chkntfs.exe', 'instnm.exe', 'ImagingDevices.exe', 'BitLockerWizardElev.exe', 'bdechangepin.exe', 'logman.exe', '.DS_Store', 'bootcfg.exe', 'DsmUserTask.exe', 'find.exe', 'LogCollector.exe', 'HxTsr.exe', 'lpq.exe', 'ctfmon.exe', 'AppInstaller.exe', 'hvsimgr.exe', 'Vcffipzmnipbxzdl.exe', 'lpremove.exe', 'hdwwiz.exe', 'CastSrv.exe', 'gpresult.exe', 'hvix64.exe', 'HvsiSettingsWorker.exe', 'fodhelper.exe', '21.exe', 'InspectVhdDialog6.2.exe', '798_abroad.exe', 'doskey.exe', 'AuditShD.exe', 'alg.exe', 'certutil.exe', 'bitsadmin.exe', 'help.exe', 'fsquirt.exe', 'PDFXCview.exe', 'inetinfo.exe', 'Win32.Wannacry.exe', 'dcdiag.exe', 'LsaIso.exe', 'lpr.exe', 'dtdump.exe', 'FileHistory.exe', 'LockApp.exe', 'AppVShNotify.exe', 'DeviceProperties.exe', 'ilasm.exe', 'CheckNetIsolation.exe', 'FilePicker.exe', 'choice.exe', 'ComSvcConfig.exe', 'Calculator.exe', 'CredDialogHost.exe', 'logagent.exe', 'InspectVhdDialog6.3.exe', 'junction.exe', 'findstr.exe', 'ktmutil.exe', 'csvde.exe', 'esentutl.exe', 'Win32.GravityRAT.exe', 'bootsect.exe', 'BdeUISrv.exe', 'ChtIME.exe', 'ARP.EXE', 'dsdbutil.exe', 'iisreset.exe', '1003.exe', 'getmac.exe', 'dllhost.exe', 'BOTBINARY.EXE', 'cscript.exe', 'dnscacheugc.exe', 'aspnet_regbrowsers.exe', 'hvax64.exe', 'CredentialUIBroker.exe', 'dpnsvr.exe', 'ApplyTrustOffline.exe', 'LxRun.exe', 'credwiz.exe', '1002.exe', 'FileExplorer.exe', 'BackgroundTransferHost.exe', 'convert.exe', 'AppVClient.exe', 'evntcmd.exe', 'attrib.exe', 'ClipUp.exe', 'DmNotificationBroker.exe', 'dcomcnfg.exe', 'dvdplay.exe', 'Dism.exe', 'AtBroker.exe', 'invoice_2318362983713_823931342io.pdf.exe', 'DataSvcUtil.exe', 'bdeunlock.exe', 'DeviceCensus.exe', 'dstokenclean.exe', 'AndroRat Binder_Patched.exe', 'iediagcmd.exe', 'comrepl.exe', 'dispdiag.exe', 'FlashUtil_ActiveX.exe', 'cliconfg.exe', 'aitstatic.exe', 'gpupdate.exe', 'GetHelp.exe', 'charmap.exe', 'aspnet_regsql.exe', 'IMEWDBLD.EXE', 'AppVStreamingUX.exe', 'dwm.exe', 'Ransomware.Unnamed_0.exe', 'csc.exe', 'bridgeunattend.exe', 'icacls.exe', 'dialer.exe', 'BdeHdCfg.exe', 'fontdrvhost.exe', '027cc450ef5f8c5f653329641ec1fed9.exe', 'LocationNotificationWindows.exe', 'dpapimig.exe', 'BitLockerDeviceEncryption.exe', 'ftp.exe', 'Eap3Host.exe', 'dfsvc.exe', 'LogonUI.exe', 'Fake Intel (1).exe', 'chglogon.exe', 'fhmanagew.exe', 'changepk.exe', 'aspnetca.exe', 'IMEPADSV.EXE', 'browserexport.exe', 'bcdboot.exe', 'aspnet_wp.exe', 'FXSCOVER.exe', 'dllhst3g.exe', 'CertEnrollCtrl.exe', 'EduPrintProv.exe', 'ielowutil.exe', 'ADSchemaAnalyzer.exe', 'cygrunsrv.exe', 'HxAccounts.exe', 'diskperf.exe', 'certreq.exe', 'bcdedit.exe', 'efsui.exe', 'klist.exe', 'raffle.exe', 'cacls.exe', 'hvc.exe', 'cmmon32.exe', 'BioIso.exe', 'AssignedAccessLockApp.exe', 'DmOmaCpMo.exe', 'AppLaunch.exe', 'AddInProcess.exe', 'dasHost.exe', 'dmcertinst.exe', 'IMJPSET.EXE', 'cmbins.exe', 'LicenseManagerShellext.exe', 'diskpart.exe', 'iscsicpl.exe', 'chown.exe', 'Magnify.exe', 'aapt.exe', 'false.exe', 'BioEnrollmentHost.exe', 'hvsirdpclient.exe', 'c2wtshost.exe', 'dplaysvr.exe', 'ChsIME.exe', 'fsavailux.exe', 'Win32.WannaPeace.exe', 'CasPol.exe', 'icsunattend.exe', 'fveprompt.exe', 'expand.exe', 'chgusr.exe', 'hvsirpcd.exe', 'MiniConfigBuilder.exe', 'FirstLogonAnim.exe', 'EDPCleanup.exe', 'ksetup.exe', 'AppVDllSurrogate.exe', 'InstallUtil.exe', 'immersivetpmvscmgrsvr.exe', 'cmdkey.exe', 'appcmd.exe', 'Build.exe', 'hostr.exe', 'CloudStorageWizard.exe', 'DWTRIG20.EXE', 'file_4571518150a8181b403df4ae7ad54ce8b16ded0c.exe', 'FsIso.exe', 'chmod.exe', 'imjpuexc.exe', 'CHXSmartScreen.exe', 'iissetup.exe', '7ZipSetup.exe', 'svchost.exe', 'ldifde.exe', 'logoff.exe', 'DiskSnapshot.exe', 'fontview.exe', 'LaunchWinApp.exe', 'GamePanel.exe', 'yfoye_dump.exe', 'ls.exe', 'HOSTNAME.EXE', 'at.exe', 'InetMgr.exe', 'FaceFodUninstaller.exe', 'InputPersonalization.exe', 'AppVNice.exe', 'ImeBroker.exe', 'CameraSettingsUIHost.exe', 'Defrag.exe', 'lpksetup.exe', 'djoin.exe', 'irftp.exe', 'DTUHandler.exe', 'LockScreenContentServer.exe', 'dsamain.exe', 'lpkinstall.exe', 'DataStoreCacheDumpTool.exe', 'dmclient.exe', 'dump1.exe', 'Cain.exe', 'AddInProcess32.exe', 'appidcertstorecheck.exe', 'IMJPUEX.EXE', 'HxOutlook.exe', 'FlashPlayerApp.exe', 'diskraid.exe', 'bthudtask.exe', 'explorer.exe', 'CompMgmtLauncher.exe', 'malware.exe', 'njRAT.exe', 'CompatTelRunner.exe', 'evntwin.exe', 'Dxpserver.exe', 'HelpPane.exe', 'cvtres.exe', 'dxdiag.exe', 'hvsievaluator.exe', 'signed.exe', 'csrss.exe', 'InstallBC201401.exe', 'audiodg.exe', 'dsregcmd.exe', 'ApproveChildRequest.exe', 'iisrstas.exe', 'chkdsk.exe', 'lodctr.exe', 'aspnet_state.exe', 'DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Service.exe', 'chgport.exe', 'cleanmgr.exe', 'GameBar.exe', 'AgentService.exe', 'InfDefaultInstall.exe', 'IMESEARCH.EXE', 'Fondue.exe', 'iexpress.exe', 'backgroundTaskHost.exe', 'dfrgui.exe', 'cofire.exe', 'BrowserCore.exe', 'clip.exe', 'appidpolicyconverter.exe', 'ed01ebfbc9eb5bbea545af4d01bf5f1071661840480439c6e5babe8e080e41aa.exe', 'cipher.exe', 'DeviceEject.exe', 'cerber.exe', '5a765351046fea1490d20f25.exe', 'CloudExperienceHostBroker.exe', 'FXSUNATD.exe', 'GenValObj.exe', 'lsass.exe', 'ddodiag.exe', 'cmstp.exe', 'wirelesskeyview.exe', 'edpnotify.exe', 'CameraBarcodeScannerPreview.exe', 'bfsvc.exe', 'eventcreate.exe', 'driverquery.exe', 'CCG.exe', 'ConfigSecurityPolicy.exe', 'ieUnatt.exe', 'eshell.exe', 'ipconfig.exe', 'jsc.exe', 'gpscript.exe', 'LaunchTM.exe', 'cttunesvr.exe', 'curl.exe', 'cttune.exe', 'DevicePairingWizard.exe', 'ByteCodeGenerator.exe', 'IEChooser.exe', 'LockAppHost.exe', 'DataExchangeHost.exe', 'dxgiadaptercache.exe', 'dsacls.exe', 'Locator.exe', 'DpiScaling.exe', 'DisplaySwitch.exe', 'autoconv.exe', 'IMJPDCT.EXE', 'ieinstal.exe', 'colorcpl.exe', 'auditpol.exe', 'dccw.exe', 'DeviceEnroller.exe', 'UpdateCheck.exe', 'LicensingUI.exe', 'ExtExport.exe', 'easinvoker.exe', 'ApplySettingsTemplateCatalog.exe', 'eventvwr.exe', 'browser_broker.exe', 'extrac32.exe', 'EaseOfAccessDialog.exe', 'label.exe', 'change.exe', 'IMCCPHR.exe', 'audit.exe', 'aspnet_compiler.exe', 'aspnet_regiis.exe', 'desktopimgdownldr.exe', 'dmcfghost.exe', 'ComputerDefaults.exe', 'control.exe', 'DeviceCredentialDeployment.exe', 'compact.exe', 'InspectVhdDialog.exe', 'EdmGen.exe', 'cmak.exe', 'AppHostRegistrationVerifier.exe', 'DataUsageLiveTileTask.exe', 'hcsdiag.exe', 'gchrome.exe', 'adamuninstall.exe', 'CloudNotifications.exe', 'dusmtask.exe', 'fc.exe', 'hh.exe', 'eudcedit.exe', 'iscsicli.exe', 'DFDWiz.exe', 'isoburn.exe', 'IMTCPROP.exe', 'CapturePicker.exe', 'abba_-_happy_new_year_zaycev_net.exe', 'finger.exe', 'ApplicationFrameHost.exe', 'calc.exe', 'counter.exe', 'editrights.exe', 'fltMC.exe', 'convertvhd.exe', 'LegacyNetUXHost.exe', 'grpconv.exe', 'ie4uinit.exe', 'dsmgmt.exe', 'fsutil.exe', 'AppResolverUX.exe', 'BootExpCfg.exe', 'conhost.exe', 'bash.exe', 'IcsEntitlementHost.exe']
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What's the value of `datasetPath`?

Comment: It is my dataset path in my machine which contains my PE files. exe files
Such as: /Users/machinename/Desktop/PE files

Comment: In order for the `for` loop to make sense, I'm thinking it must be a *list* of paths. Please [edit] your question to clarify this.

Comment: Just edit it. 
I hope it makes sense now

Comment: Not really no. I tried to answer anyway.

Comment: I hope is makes sense now. I posted the whole file samples in the datasetpath

Comment: So you simply want to check if one or more of files exist in the current directory...?

Comment: What is a PE file anyway?

Comment: @Mast Windows executable file type; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally.

For some reason it did not run properly on the Macintosh machine therefore I used the same code to run it on Linux and windows and it ran successfully.

The problem was with this line specifically:

```
samples = [f for f in os.listdir(datasetPath) if isfile(join(datasetPath, f))]
```

Answer (score 1):

(Edited in reaction to question updates; probably scroll down to the end.)

This probably contains more than one bug:

```py
for directories in datasetPath: # directories iterating over my datasetPath which contains list of my pe files
    samples = [f for f in os.listdir(datasetPath) if isfile(join(datasetPath, f))]
    for file in samples:
        filePath = directories+"/"+file
        fileByteSequence = readFile(filePath)
```

Without knowledge of the precise data types here, it's hard to know exactly how to fix this. But certainly, if `datasetPath` is a list of paths, `os.path.join(datasetPath, f)` will not produce what you hope and expect.

Assuming `datasetPath` contains something like `[r'A:\', r'c:\windows\kill me now']`, a more or less logical rewrite could look something like

```py
for dir in datasetPath:
    samples = []
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        p = os.path.join(dir, f)
        if isfile(p):
            samples.append(p)
    for filePath in samples:
        fileByteSequence = readFile(filePath)
```

Notice how we produce the full path just once, and then keep that. Notice how we use the loop variable `dir` inside the loop, not the list of paths we are looping over.

Actually I'm guessing `datasetPath` is actually a string, but then the `for` loop makes no sense (you end up looping over the characters in the string one by one).

If you merely want to check which of these files exist in the current directory, you are massively overcomplicating things.

```
for filePath in os.listdir('.'):
    if filePath in datasetPath:
        fileByteSequence = readFile(filePath)
```

Whether you loop over the files on the disk and check which ones are on you list or vice versa is not a crucial design detail; I have preferred the former on the theory that you want to minimize the number of disk accesses (in the ideal case you get all file names from the disk with a single system call).

Comment: Even after implementing simple for loop. 
I am still getting error : [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'Desktop' 
Could it be Windows/Linux issue with

samples = [f for f in listdir(datasetPath) if isfile(join(datasetPath, f))] .   ?

Comment: It has to do with the file path and it is not pick it up correctly. It sees it as string.